# How to access through all the entry boxes and make them blank

Tags: python, tkinter

As a new python learner, I was trying to create a form in Tkinter with some entry boxes which takes some values from a user. For that I have used For loop to create a 4x2 matrix of entry boxes and filled them with some dummy names.
Now I was wondering how to make all these boxes blank in one shot. The function that I created only makes last entry box blank. I am trying access through all the boxes one by one to make them blank but not able to do.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
master.geometry("175x175")

def clear():
    e1.delete(0, END)


for y in range(4):
    for i in range(2):
        e1 = Entry(master)
        e1.grid(row = y, column = i, padx = 20, pady= 10)
        if y == 0:
            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'Vishal')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')

        elif y == 1:
            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'ashish')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')

        elif y == 2:
            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'vikas')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')

        else:

            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'sacHin')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')


btn = Button(master, text = 'Clear', command = clear)
btn.grid(row= 4, column = 1)

master.mainloop()
```

please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are only holding the last Entry you create, you will need to hold all of them. change your code like this:

```
entries = [] # note these changes
def clear():
    for item in entries:
        item.delete(0, END)


for y in range(4):
    for i in range(2):
        e1 = Entry(master)
        entries.append(e1) # and this change
        e1.grid(row = y, column = i, padx = 20, pady= 10)
        if y == 0:
            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'Vishal')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')

        elif y == 1:
            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'ashish')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')

        elif y == 2:
            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'vikas')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')

        else:

            if i == 0:
                e1.insert(0,'sacHin')
            else:
                e1.insert(0,'Mishra')
```

Comment: Yes I understand that in my code only the last entry box get the e1 name that's why it got blank only. But how to hold all these boxes together?

Comment: literally look at what i posted, i even marked the relevant bits with `# comments`